# improving speed of file existence checking

Tags: php

I use this code to check for file existence. It must use a wildcard:

```
$cachedFileResultArray = glob( '/directory/' . "$slugUrl*" ) ?? null;
```

From my understanding it will not stop upon first hit.
Is there a way to improve this process, such as stop looking after first hit ? Or any other way to accomplish this the fastest way possible ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you could use [DirectoryIterator](http://php.net/manual/ru/class.directoryiterator.php) to speed up search. Try this function and benchmark perfomance.

```
function globIterator($dir, $pattern) {
    $directory = new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($dir);
    $iterator = new RecursiveIteratorIterator($directory);
    foreach($iterator as $file) {
        if (preg_match($pattern, $file) === 1){
            return $file;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

If wildcard is not a regex, it would be good to replace `preg_match` to `strpos`, as PHP documentation [recommends](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php), so `foreach` loop will lock like this:

```
foreach ($iterator as $file) {
    if (strpos($file, $pattern) !== false) {
        return $file;
    }
}
```