# Reduce speed to determine hdfs dfs file existence

Tags: performance, hadoop, mapreduce, hdfs, file-exists

I am trying to determine if a number of paths exist in hadoop fs using: `hdfs fs -test -e filename`
However, as I begin to use wildcard `*` characters in a path to search through all of my directories to find a specific file (for example: `/*/*/*/*/*/fileName`, etc.), this significantly slows down the process as the test function searches through all directories. While I need this power to be able to find files (I am using a company hadoop cluster where I do not know where a specific file is stored), I would like to know if there is any way to speed up the process similar to this [question about php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43398288/improving-speed-of-file-existence-checking).

I originally used `hdfs fs -test -e filename` as opposed to `hdfs fs -ls filename` to test that a file exists after reading this [link](https://community.hortonworks.com/questions/49312/hdfs-file-exists-check.html), because I could easily determine if a file existed without throwing an error, but I am willing to change my code given a better alternative.

**I would like to know the best (least time consuming) way to determine if a file exists in hadoop fs given a variable file path location.**

- Can I perform the search starting from the most current modified directory given the variable file path location?
- Is it possible to terminate the search once the file has been found or will the search continue running until all paths have been checked?
- Since I am only checking for file existence before I pass the file into a mapreduce job to avoid errors when the job tries to read from the file, should I forget about this time consuming check and simply attempt to catch an error thrown when a file path does not exist?

Comment: I think 3rd option is better than others i.e. try to check if the file exist in your mapreduce job itself and then catch an error thrown when a file path does not exist